# Why is my DocuSign request for templates returning an empty list?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to retrieve a list of templates for a client account. The rest api call looks like this:
https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxxx/templates (with the account id where the xs are).

We have verified that the client has five templates. Yet the call always returns this:

```
{
  "resultSetSize": "0",
  "startPosition": "0",
  "endPosition": "0",
  "totalSetSize": "0"
}
```

The documentation says none of the parameters are required, so I assume that the call above should return ALL templates. What else could be causing this to fail?

Comment: Does their account really exist on NA2? or is their account on another server?

Comment: Turns out the client was trying to access templates in their test account. Never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up with the comments here, make sure you are testing with the proper account.  In you post you've included NA2 in your URL, if you are writing an integration and have not moved to production yet then try checking your developer sandbox account (i.e. `https://DEMO.docusign.net`).  Otherwise if you have templates in a production account that resides on NA2 then they should be returned in the call.